# I want to generate a WordCloud for the "best" and the "worst" reviews from a DataFrame in Python

Tags: python

I have currently got a dataframe for hotel reviews, with "city" (the hotel is in) "name" (of the hotel) "rating" (of the review) "review" (the actual review)

I want to generate a WordCloud for reviews with rating = 5 and a WordCloud for reviews with rating = 1.

I can only work out how to generate a WordCloud for the whole DataFrame at this point.

Comment: ah yes, the good old 0 context 0 example given questions. I see you're a new contributor though, so it's fine. `Please make sure you explain your question clearly, understandable to anyone, and provide example if possible. In your question, perhaps provide an example for the dataframe? What's the structure?` "I can only work out how to generate a WordCloud for the whole DataFrame at this point." `Great! Show it! Show us what you have tried, code would be great`~

Comment: You should try providing a minimal, reproducible example of your input. That being said, if your dataframe is called df and the column is called reviews, you should probably just do `df[df.reviews == 5]` and  `df[df.reviews == 0]` and pass these to the word cloud functions

Comment: It's always a good idea to do some research before asking a question. This can often be much faster than simply asking before researching, and what's more can be significantly more educational both in how to search and in what you find out there. PLUS you won't get downvotes/votes to close/sarcasm. Have you done any research? Tthe starting point would be to use a popular search engine and give it the most significant keywords like in this case __python wordcloud__ and then review the results. Then if you still have to ask a question, explain that research didn't show any suitable results.